# Focusing issues

Tags: newtonian-telescope

I have an 8 inch Skywatcher scope. I have collimated it with a laser collimator but when I tried to study the moon I got just a bright ball and on stars I could see nothing. My lens are a super 10 mm, a super 25 wide angle with a 2x Barlow. Does anyone have any suggestions please.

Comment: That sounds like you need to change the length of you optical path more than your focus adjustment currently allows. Try whether it works if you slowly pull out the eye piece

Comment: And when doing that use the lowest magnification (longest focal length eyepiece, presumably the 25 mm) and do not use the Barlow.

Comment: Thank you will give it a try.

Comment: Have you double-checked all the calibration instructions - not just collimation?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, will check that out.